# Combine CNN and LSTM for text Multi-class classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I build a model consisting of one CNN and one LSTM. CNN to extract the features and pass that to LSTM. I am working with a Multi-class text classification problem, the input for CNN is TF-IDF.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Flatten,Activation
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import CategoricalAccuracy, AUC
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,Conv1D,MaxPooling1D

from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
    
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=( 1500,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),batch_size=512)
```

The error as follows:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_33 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 1, 1500)
```

Answer (score 0):

the model expects an input_shape of 1, 1500 and you are giving one with 1500,1. change your input in the model from `model.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=( 1500,1)))` to `model.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=( 1, 1500)))`
but there might be more errors with the format after that i'm not sure if you can just add the lstm in your model.

Comment: When I changed the input shaped toinput_shape=( 1, 1500)  , the following error appear:  ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for '{{node conv1d_1/conv1d}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv1d_1/conv1d/ExpandDims, conv1d_1/conv1d/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,1500], [1,5,1500,128].